# Parameterized SQL in Presto on Presto CLI

Tags: presto, trino

Is there any option to provide parameters on Presto CLI.

I am trying to change my impala-shell command to Presto where my HQL file gets parameter from command line of impala like below.

`impala-shell -f ot_full.hql --var=date_next=${date_next_para} --var=yrmth=${yrmth_para} --var=yrmth_L12=${yrmth_L12_para} --var=pyrmth=${pyrmth_para}`

`WITH` clause in presto is not that much helpful.

How can we convert it to Presto command line.

I did not find any documentation/example on this in https://prestodb.io/docs/current/

Comment: Perhaps not that useful, but what injecting parameters with `sed`: about `cat ot_full.hql | sed -e "s/date_next/${date_next_para}/" .. | presto-cli` ?

Answer (score 8):

The Presto .CLI doesn't support this, so you'll need to substitute the variables in the SQL query before passing it to the CLI. One way is to do this directly in shell:

```sh
presto --execute "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ds >= '${date_next_para}'"
```

For longer queries, using a [here document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) is a good option.

Comment: Surely given workaround will work but do we have any plan to provide such functionality in future development?

Comment: @Shawn looks like a popular feature request but not implemented https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/5918